# How to transfer a large ADO recordset in Access 2013 to a CSV file?

Tags: sql-server, vba, csv, ado

I'm running into some performance issues when transferring a large ADO recordset from Access 2013 to a new CSV file.

My requirements are:
1) File must contain column names
2) Recordset can contain more than 500,000 records
3) File must be comma delimited
4) Records have alphanumeric strings that sometimes contain commas
5) The program must create a new CSV file (not just update a pre-existing one)
Note: The data is stored in a recordset because it's queried from an MS-SQL Server

I'm relatively new to VBA programming so any help would be greatly appreciated. I read that GetRows loops that run from the beginning to the end of file can be an efficient process for exporting large recordsets to CSV. THANKS

This is my current implementation that obviously violates a number of my requirements:

```
    'WRITE DATA TO TEXT FILE
     Dim f As ADODB.Field
     Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
     Dim txtfile As Object
     Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     Set txtfile = myFileSystemObject.CreateTextFile(strPath & ".txt", True)
     With adRs
      For Each f In .Fields
         txtfile.Write (f.Name)
         txtfile.Write Chr(9)
      Next
      txtfile.WriteLine
      txtfile.Write adRs.GetString(adClipString)
      .Close
     End With
     txtfile.Close
```

Comment: You have a bad problem: `3) File must be comma delimited
 4) Records have alphanumeric strings that sometimes contain commas` this is just bad. If you data has commas in it, and that's your separator, you lose you column boundaries. You need to use a different separator character, such as `|`, if you have commas. Otherwise, the only way to handle that is to make all fields fixed width, which means if column A is 50 characters, then it will need to be padded with a space for every character it doesn't have. But this lets you know that a comma is EMBEDDED in the data, rather than a separator.

Comment: @StarPilot - standard CSV method for handling fields with commas is to quote them. It's not a big problem.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Problem with using quotes is when data contains quotes, which is common if you have user general use fields in the data, such as a comments or notes column. Then you are stuck at using yet another character for divisor, fixed length input fields, or trying to detect these quotes and escape or transform them. Easiest way to avoid headaches is fixed length fields with separator (for human eyes), or rarely used character as separator. Fixed length compresses well, and a simple trim eliminates the whitespace padding.

Comment: @StarPilot - my point was really just that CSV has standard methods for handling this type of thing - including quotes (doubled up). Since the OP has a requirement for CSV output, they can just follow those methods to produce an Excel-compatible output.

Comment: @TimWilliams - My past experiences is that many don't implement the standards appropriately, and you end up getting burned for it. So I've developed the attitude it is best to take a few precautions whenever possible and save yourself the heartburn when you find yet another instance where the standard wasn't met. But I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (though I don't know performance will be affected; your question seems to be twofold - how do I get my results and then how can I do it efficiently).

```
'WRITE DATA TO TEXT FILE
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Dim myFileSystemObject As Object
Dim txtfile As Object
Dim str As String

Set myFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set txtfile = myFileSystemObject.CreateTextFile(strPath & ".txt", True)

With adRs
    For Each f In .Fields
        txtfile.Write (f.Name)
        txtfile.Write Chr(9)
    Next

    txtfile.WriteLine

    'Add in leading double quote, double quote text qualifier throughout, and changing carriage returns to double quote/carriage return/double quote.
    str = Chr(34) & Replace(Replace(adRs.GetString, vbTab, Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)), vbCr, Chr(34) & vbCr & Chr(34))

    'Write to file removing last extraneous double quote.
    txtfile.Write Mid(str, 1, Len(str) - 1)

    .Close
    End With

txtfile.Close
```

All the code is doing is adding a " to the beginning of the string, changing all previous tab characters to "," and changing all carriage returns to "[cr]".  The Replace in the Write function should remove the last extraneous ".  The text delimiter should protect any embedded commas.  Again, not sure of performance, but seems like you can get something up and running to your specs, at least.

EDIT: If this doesn't get you where you want to be, you can check out SQL Server's BCP utility as well.

Comment: VBlades, thanks a ton for the help! The solution you gave works well for smaller files and solves the CSV double quote issue. For the bigger files, I'll take your suggestion and explore a server side solution. I found this useful blog covering one way to use the BCP utility here: [link]http://www.drewgillson.com/blog/export-data-sql-server-csv/

Comment: Cool, no worries.  If you think it is a decent answer you can mark it off as such.  That may help someone who runs across this issue in the future.

Comment: Sorry VBLades it looks like my reputation is not high enough yet. Once I boost my rep, I'll make sure to upvote. Thanks

Comment: No worries, but you shouldn't need to have a high rep to select a solution for your question.  It's not the same as giving it an upvote.  Not a big deal, though, SO has saved me lots of times and just want someone to know there is a workable solution to this question if it ever comes up again.  Take care.

Comment: Thanks VBlades now I got it, sorry such a noob.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game here - the question's over 3 years old! - and you've got an answer that implements encapsulating text fields in quotes, which is the marker for a competent answer.

However, there are very few answers out there that address the three big issues:

1. Optimising away VBA's clunky string-handling;
2. The Byte Order Marker, which VBA embeds in every string it saves to
   file, ensuring that some of the most common consumers of a csv file
   cannot read it properly;
3. ...And there's never any middle ground between writing the file
   line-by-line, forever, and writing it in one big chunk that'll throw
   an out-of-memory error.

Beginners in VBA may find the string-optimisations difficult to understand: the biggest performance gain available in native VBA is to avoid string allocation and concatenation ( here's why: http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/stringopt2.html#huge ) - so I use join, split, and replace instead of `myString = MyString & MoreString`

The trailing loop, with the `RecordSet.GetRows()` call at the very end, will raise eyebrows among coders with strong opinions about structured programming.

So here goes:

```
 Public Function RecordsetToCSV(ByRef rst As ADODB.Recordset, _
                                ByRef OutputFile As String, _
                                Optional ByRef FieldList As Variant, _
                                Optional ByVal CoerceText As Boolean = True, _
                                Optional ByVal CleanupText As Boolean = True _
                                ) As Long
```

' Output a recordset to a csv file and returns the row count.

' If the output file is locked, or specified in an inaccessible location, the
' 'ByRef' OutputFile parameter becomes a file in the user's local temp folder

' You can supply your own field list. This isn't a substituted file header of
' aliased field names: it is a subset of the field names, which ADO will read
' selectively from the recordset. Each item in the list matches a named field

' CoerceText=TRUE will encapsulate all items, numeric or not, in quote marks.
' CleanupText=TRUE strips quotes and linefeeds from the data: FALSE is faster

' You should only set them FALSE if you're confident that the data is 'clean'
' with no quote marks, commas or line breaks in any unencapsulated text field

' This code handles unicode, and outputs a file that can be read by Microsoft
' ODBC and OLEDB database drivers by removing the Byte Order Marker.

On Error Resume Next

' Coding note: we're not doing any string-handling in VBA.Strings: allocating
' deallocating and (especially!) concatenating are SLOW. We are using the VBA
' Join and Split functions ONLY. Feel free to optimise further by declaring a
' faster set of string functions from the Kernel if you want to.
'
' Other optimisations: type pun. Byte Arrays are interchangeable with strings
' Some of our loops through these arrays have a 'step' of 2. This optimises a
' search-and-replace for ANSI chars in an array of 2-byte unicodes. Note that
' it's only used to remove known ANSI 'Latin' characters with a 'low' byte of
' zero: any other use of the two-byte 'step' will fail on non-Latin unicodes.

' ** THIS CODE IS IN THE PUBLIC DOMAIN **
'   Nigel Heffernan   Excellerando.Blogspot.com

Const FETCH_ROWS As Long = 4096

Dim COMMA As String * 1
Dim BLANK As String * 4
Dim EOROW As String * 2

COMMA = ChrW$(44)
 BLANK = ChrW$(13) & ChrW$(10) & ChrW$(13) & ChrW$(10)
 EOROW = ChrW$(13) & ChrW$(10)

Dim FetchArray  As Variant

Dim i As Long ' i for rows in the output file, records in the recordset
Dim j As Long ' j for columns in the output file, fields in the recordset
Dim k As Long ' k for all other loops: bytes in individual data items

Dim i_Offset As Long

Dim i_LBound As Long
Dim i_UBound As Long
Dim j_LBound As Long
Dim j_UBound As Long
Dim k_lBound As Long
Dim k_uBound As Long

Dim hndFile  As Long
Dim varField As Variant

Dim iRowCount  As Long
Dim arrBytes() As Byte
Dim arrTemp1() As String
Dim arrTemp2() As String
Dim arrTemp3(0 To 2) As String

Dim boolNumeric As Boolean

Dim strHeader   As String
Dim arrHeader() As Byte

Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strExtn As String

strFile = FileName(OutputFile)
strPath = FilePath(OutputFile)
strExtn = FileExtension(strFile)

If rst Is Nothing Then Exit Function
If rst.State <> 1 Then Exit Function

If strExtn = "" Then
    strExtn = ".csv"
End If

With FSO

```
If strFile = "" Then
    strFile = .GetTempName
    strFile = Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - Len(".tmp"))
    strFile = strFile & strExtn
End If

If strPath = "" Then
    strPath = TempSQLFolder
End If

If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    strPath = strPath & "\"
End If

strExtn = FileExtension(strFile)
If strExtn = "" Then
    strExtn = ".csv"
    strFile = strFile & strExtn
End If


OutputFile = strPath & strFile
```

End With

If FileName(OutputFile) <> "" Then
    If Len(VBA.FileSystem.Dir(OutputFile, vbNormal)) <> 0 Then

```
    Err.Clear
    VBA.FileSystem.Kill OutputFile  ' do it now, and reduce wait for deletion
    If Err.Number = 70 Then  ' permission denied: change the output file name
        OutputFile = FileStripExtension(OutputFile) & "_" & FileStripExtension(FSO.GetTempName) & FileExtension(OutputFile)
    End If

End If
```

End If

' ChrW$() gives a 2-byte 'Wide' char. This coerces all subsequent operations to UTF16

arrTemp3(0) = ChrW$(34)       ' Encapsulating quote
arrTemp3(1) = vbNullString    ' The field value will go here
arrTemp3(2) = ChrW$(34)       ' Encapsulating quote

If rst.EOF And rst.BOF Then
    FetchArray = Empty
ElseIf rst.EOF Then
    rst.MoveFirst
End If

' An empty recordset must still write a header row of field names: we put this in the
' output buffer and write it to the file before we start looping through the records.

ReDim FetchArray(0 To rst.Fields.Count, 0 To 0)

i_LBound = 0
i_UBound = 0

If IsMissing(FieldList) Then

```
For j = LBound(FetchArray, 1) To UBound(FetchArray, 1) - 1 Step 1
    FetchArray(j, i_UBound) = rst.Fields(j).Name
Next j
```

Else

```
j = 0

For Each varField In FieldList
    j_UBound = j_UBound + 1
Next varField

ReDim arrTemp2(j_LBound To j_UBound)
For Each varField In FieldList
    FetchArray(j, i_UBound) = CStr(varField)
    j = j + 1
Next varField
```

End If

ReDim arrTemp1(i_LBound To i_UBound)    ' arrTemp1 is the rowset we write to file
ReDim arrTemp2(j_LBound To j_UBound)    ' arrTemp2 represents a single record

Do Until IsEmpty(FetchArray)

```
i_LBound = LBound(FetchArray, 2)
i_UBound = UBound(FetchArray, 2)

j_LBound = LBound(FetchArray, 1)
j_UBound = UBound(FetchArray, 1)

If UBound(arrTemp1) <> i_UBound + 1 Then
    ReDim arrTemp1(i_LBound To i_UBound + 1)
    arrTemp1(i_UBound + 1) = vbNullString   ' The 'Join' operation will insert a trailing row
End If                                      ' delimiter here (Not required by the last chunk)

If UBound(arrTemp2) <> j_UBound Then
    ReDim arrTemp2(j_LBound To j_UBound)
End If


' Data body. This is heavily optimised to avoid VBA String functions with allocations

For i = i_LBound To i_UBound Step 1

    ' If this is confusing... Were you expecting FetchArray(i,j)? i for row, j for column?
    ' FetchArray comes from RecordSet.GetRows(), which returns a TRANSPOSED array: i and j
    ' are still the field and record ordinals, row(i) and column(j) in the output file.

    For j = j_LBound To j_UBound

        If IsNull(FetchArray(j, i)) Then
            arrTemp2(j) = ""
        Else
            arrTemp2(j) = FetchArray(j, i)  ' confused? see he note above
        End If

        If CleanupText Or (i_UBound = 0) Then  ' (i_UBound=0): always clean up field names

            arrBytes = arrTemp2(j) ' Integer arithmetic is faster than string-handling for
                                   ' this: all VBA string operations require an allocation

            For k = LBound(arrBytes) To UBound(arrBytes) Step 2

                Select Case arrBytes(k)
                Case 10, 13, 9, 160
                    If arrBytes(k + 1) = 0 Then
                        arrBytes(k) = 32 ' replaces CR, LF, Tab, and non-breaking
                    End If               ' spaces with the standard ANSI space
                Case 44
                    If Not CoerceText Then
                        If arrBytes(k + 1) = 0 Then
                            arrBytes(k) = 32 ' replace comma with the ANSI space
                        End If
                    End If
                Case 34
                    If arrBytes(k + 1) = 0 Then
                        arrBytes(k) = 39  ' replaces double-quote with single quote
                    End If
                End Select

            Next k

            arrTemp2(j) = arrTemp2(j)

        End If  ' cleanup


        If CoerceText Then  ' encapsulate all fields in quotes, numeric or not

           arrTemp3(1) = arrTemp2(j)
           arrTemp2(j) = Join$(arrTemp3, vbNullString)

        ElseIf (i = 0) And (i = i_UBound) Then ' always encapsulate field names

           arrTemp3(1) = arrTemp2(j)
           arrTemp2(j) = Join$(arrTemp3, vbNullString)

        Else ' selective encapsulation, leaving numeric fields unencapsulated:
             ' we *could* do this by reading the ADODB field types: but that's
             ' slower, and you may be 'caught out' by provider-specific types.

            arrBytes = arrTemp2(j)

            boolNumeric = True

            For k = LBound(arrBytes) To UBound(arrBytes) Step 2
                If arrBytes(k) < 43 Or arrBytes(k) > 57 Then

                    If arrBytes(k) <> 69 Then
                        boolNumeric = False
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        If k > UBound(arrBytes) - 5 Then
                            boolNumeric = False
                            Exit For
                        ElseIf arrBytes(k + 2) = 45 Then
                            ' detect "1.234E-05"
                        ElseIf arrBytes(k + 2) = 43 Then
                            ' detect "1.234E+05"
                        Else
                            boolNumeric = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If

                End If
            Next k

            If boolNumeric Then
               For k = 1 + LBound(arrBytes) To UBound(arrBytes) Step 2
                   If arrBytes(k) <> 0 Then
                       boolNumeric = False
                       Exit For
                   End If
               Next k
            End If

           arrBytes = vbNullString

           If Not boolNumeric Then ' text field, encapsulate it
               arrTemp3(1) = arrTemp2(j)
               arrTemp2(j) = Join(arrTemp3, vbNullString)
           End If

        End If ' CoerceText

    Next j

   arrTemp1(i) = Join(arrTemp2, COMMA)

Next i

iRowCount = iRowCount + i - 2


'   **** WHY WE 'PUT' A BYTE ARRAY INSTEAD OF A VBA STRING VARIABLE  **** ****
'
'       Put #hndFile, , StrConv(Join(arrTemp1, EOROW), vbUnicode)
'       Put #hndFile, , Join(arrTemp1, EOROW)
'
'   If you pass unicode, Wide or UTF-16 string variables to PUT, it prepends a
'   Unicode Byte Order Mark to the data which, when written to your file, will
'   render the field names illegible to Microsoft's JET ODBC and ACE-OLEDB SQL
'   drivers (which can actually read unicode field names, if the helpful label
'   isn't in the way). The primeval 'PUT' statement writes a Byte array as-is.
'
'   **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** **** ****


arrBytes = Join$(arrTemp1, vbCrLf)


If hndFile = 0 Then

    i_Offset = 1
    If Len(Dir(OutputFile)) > 0 Then
        VBA.FileSystem.Kill OutputFile
    End If

    WaitForFileDeletion OutputFile

    hndFile = FreeFile
    Open OutputFile For Binary Access Write As #hndFile

End If


Put #hndFile, i_Offset, arrBytes
i_Offset = i_Offset + 1 + UBound(arrBytes)
Erase arrBytes


If rst.EOF Then
    Erase FetchArray
    FetchArray = Empty
Else
    If IsMissing(FieldList) Then
        FetchArray = rst.GetRows(FETCH_ROWS)
    Else
        FetchArray = rst.GetRows(FETCH_ROWS, , FieldList)
    End If
End If
```

Loop   ' until isempty(FetchArray)

If iRowCount < 1 Then  '
    iRowCount = 0      ' Row Count excludes the header
End If

RecordsetToCSV = iRowCount

ExitSub:

```
On Error Resume Next

If hndFile <> 0 Then
    Close #hndFile
End If

Erase arrBytes
Erase arrTemp1
Erase arrTemp2
Exit Function
```

ErrSub:

```
Resume ExitSub
```

End Function

Public Function FilePath(Path As String) As String
' Strip the filename from a path, leaving only the path to the folder
' The last char of this path will be the backslash

' This does not check for the existence or accessibility of the file:
' all we're doing here is string-handling

Dim strPath   As String
Dim arrPath() As String

Const BACKSLASH As String * 1 = "\"

strPath = Trim(Path)

If strPath = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strPath, 1) = BACKSLASH Then Exit Function

arrPath = Split(strPath, BACKSLASH)

If UBound(arrPath) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FilePath = ""
Else
    arrPath(UBound(arrPath)) = vbNullString
    FilePath = Join$(arrPath, BACKSLASH)
End If

Erase arrPath

End Function

Public Function FileName(Path As String) As String
' Strip the folder and path from a file's path string, leaving only the file name

' This does not check for the existence or accessibility of the file:
' all we're doing here is string-handling

Dim strPath   As String
Dim arrPath() As String

Const BACKSLASH As String * 1 = "\"

strPath = Trim(Path)

If strPath = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strPath, 1) = BACKSLASH Then Exit Function

arrPath = Split(strPath, BACKSLASH)

If UBound(arrPath) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FileName = Path
Else
    FileName = arrPath(UBound(arrPath))
End If

Erase arrPath

End Function

Public Function FileExtension(Path As String) As String
' Return the extension of the file

' This is just string-handling: no file or path validation is attempted
' The file extension is deemed to be whatever comes after the final '.'
' The extension is returned with the dot, eg: ".txt" not "txt"
' If no extension is detected, FileExtension returns an empty string

Dim strFile   As String
Dim arrFile() As String
Const DOT_EXT As String * 1 = "."

strFile = FileName(Path)
strFile = Trim(strFile)

If strFile = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strFile, 1) = DOT_EXT Then Exit Function

arrFile = Split(strFile, DOT_EXT)

If UBound(arrFile) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FileExtension = vbNullString
Else
    FileExtension = arrFile(UBound(arrFile))
    FileExtension = Trim(FileExtension)
    If Len(FileExtension) > 0 Then
        FileExtension = DOT_EXT & FileExtension
    End If
End If

Erase arrFile

End Function

Public Function FileStripExtension(Path As String) As String
' Return the filename, with the extension removed

' This is just string-handling:  no file validation is attempted
' The file extension is deemed to be whatever comes after the final '.'
' Both the dot and the extension are removed

Dim strFile   As String
Dim arrFile() As String
Const DOT_EXT As String * 1 = "."

strFile = FileName(Path)

If strFile = "" Then Exit Function
If Right$(strFile, 1) = DOT_EXT Then Exit Function

strFile = Trim(strFile)

arrFile = Split(strFile, DOT_EXT)

If UBound(arrFile) = 0 Then          ' does not contain "\"
    FileStripExtension = vbNullString
Else
    ReDim Preserve arrFile(LBound(arrFile) To UBound(arrFile) - 1)
    FileStripExtension = Join$(arrFile, DOT_EXT)
End If

Erase arrFile

End Function

You'll also need the three path-and-file-name utility functions, if you don't have your own versions already:

- FileName()
- FilePath()
- FileStripExtension()

There's room for improvement in the string-encapsulation logic: the **correct** approach is to look up the recordset's field types and apply quote marks accordingly, and it may well turn out to be faster than my clunky byte-counting approach. However, my approach is all about the file consumers and what they *expect* to see; and that doesn't always line up with what *ought* to accept.

If you succeed in coding a faster and more robust version do, please, let me know.